# Removing invalid named ranges with Sheets API and GAS

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

Here is my function:

```
function deleteNamedRangeWithREF() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var spreadsheetId = ss.getId();
   var spreadsheetObject = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(spreadsheetId);
   var namedRanges = spreadsheetObject.namedRanges;
   Logger.log(namedRanges);
   var namedRangesRef = [];
   for(var i = 0; i < namedRanges.length; i++)
   {
     if((namedRanges[i].range.endColumnIndex - namedRanges[i].range.startColumnIndex) <= 0 || (namedRanges[i].range.endRowIndex - namedRanges[i].range.startRowIndex) <= 0)
       namedRangesRef.push(namedRanges[i].namedRangeId);
   }
   var BUrequest = Sheets.newBatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
   BUrequest.requests = [];
   for(var i = 0; i < namedRangesRef.length; i++)
   {
     var request = {
                     deleteNamedRange: {
                       namedRangeId: namedRangesRef[i]
                     }
     }
     BUrequest.requests.push(request)
   }
   if (BUrequest.requests.length)
     Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(BUrequest, spreadsheetId);
}
```

I'm using sheets API to delete bad `#REF` named ranges.

When coding this, this worked, but now looks like it's broken.

You can see by yourself @`Logger.log(namedRanges);` all listed named ranges are valid, it doesn't retrieve the `#REF` named ranges.

Did google changed something, is there an alternative?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is the direction you want, in my environment, when ``range.sheetId`` is not included in the object in the array of ``namedRanges``, I'm using as the situation that the named range cannot be used. Can this method be used for your situation?

Comment: @Tanaike many thanks for your comment. Only problem is that I don't get those ranges. I can't get invalid ranges. Did you tried? :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. When the namedRange with ``#REF`` is retrieved, ``sheetId`` is not including in the response value. But the range can be retrieved as the grid range. If I misunderstood your situation, please tel me.

Comment: @Tanaike :) Thanks. What I'm telling is that the range with `#REF` is not retrieved at all.

Comment: For example, when you retrieve the namedRange of ``#REF`` using your script, the range of the retrieved object becomes ``range: {}``. If my understanding is correct, in order to correctly understand your situation, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet for replicating your situation. I would like to confirm about it.

Comment: @Tanaike sure I will do that

Comment: here @Tanaike is the [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QxdLQqHx5fQIoV-CHoyzGbJD8HDKYB2Jrr7O6K7ZyIw/edit#gid=579469817) as you can see on the console log it doesn't retrieve the invalid range.Many thanks in advance

Comment: Thank you for replying and sharing the sample Spreadsheet. I could correctly see your situation. And I had never seen your situation. So I investigated about this situation, and I posted my answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 2):

At first, I have to apologize and modify my comments in your question. At Sheets API, when there is no value of object, the property is not created. For example, `sheetId` of `gid=0` is not shown in the range object. (But I'm not sure whether it occurs at all response patterns of Sheets API.) About this, I had forgot it. I have to apologize for this situation.

By considering above situation, I investigated your sample Spreadsheet. As the results, it was found as follows.

1. NamedRange with `PlageNommée1` could be retrieved by Sheets API. In this case, although the range is included as the grid range, `sheetId` is not included in the range object because the sheet ID is `0`.
2. NamedRange with `PlageNommée2` couldn't be retrieved by Sheets API. In this case, the range object related to `PlageNommée2` couldn't be retrieved, although `sheetId` of `PlageNommée2` is not `0`.

   - I think that when the grid range is `#REF!`, Sheets API might use this as no namedRange.

From above situation, I thought that Spreadsheet Service instead of Sheets API might be able to retrieve values. So I tested this. The sample script using Spreadsheet Service is as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
var id = "### spreadsheetId ###"; // Please set this.
var namedRanges = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getNamedRanges();
for (var i = 0; i < namedRanges.length; i++) {
  Logger.log("name: %s, range: %s!%s",
    namedRanges[i].getName(),
    namedRanges[i].getRange().getSheet().getSheetName(),
    namedRanges[i].getRange().getA1Notation()
  )
}
```

#### Result:

```
name: "PlageNommée1", range: "Feuille 1!A1"
name: "PlageNommée2", range: "Feuille 2!#REF!"
```

- In this case, the range of `Feuille 2` can be retrieved as `#REF!`. From this result, you can check the namedRanges.
- It was found that the namedRange of `PlageNommée2` could be retrieved by Spreadsheet Service, even if the range is `#REF!`.

#### Reference:

- [getNamedRanges()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getnamedranges)

Comment: Many thanks for this answer @Tanaike. weird thing is that I'v tested the `SpreadsheetApp`service before and I got a "server error". so I will try again. Thanks :)

Comment: I've just tested it on and got a "server error". Didn't got one on the test sheet I've sent you though really weird.

Comment: @JSmith Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In my environment, I confirmed that when I run the script, the script worked fine. So I couldn't replicate your situation. I apologize for this situation. Can you provide the detail flow for replicating your issue? I would like to confirm your situation.

Comment: @JSmith Although I tested several situations, when above script is run, I couldn't find the method for occurring ``server error``. And also, when I directly used your shared Spreadsheet from my standalone script, the script worked fine. So for example, how about creating new standalone script or bound script, and copying and pasting only above script, then running the script? I apologize I couldn't replicate your situation. This is due to my poor skill.

Comment: don't say that no problem many thanks for your help. I will try reproduce the error and get back to you. The script worked fine with the shared spreadsheet. Again many thanks.

Comment: @JSmith Thank you for replying. Thank you for testing it. I'm glad the script worked for the shared Spreadsheet. About your issue of ``server error``, I cannot replicate it yet. I apologize for this.